# Block SQL Injection entry in a jtextfield using regex

Tags: java, regex, jtextfield

Is any other way to block sql injection in a textfield using regex?
This is what I use to block some special characters:

```
private static final String PATTERN =
        "([^A-Za-z0-9.,'\"% _-]+)";
```

Just as I've said, SOME. I want to block ALL if possible and I only want to use regex. Please help. :)

Comment: Think about this  how common are words like "insert", "update" and "delete"?

Comment: If you're *blocking* the characters that match the pattern, then you are **not** blocking single and double quote (because you included them in a negative character class) and those are the characters that make SQL injection possible.

Answer (score 3):

The right way would be to use a `PreparedStatement` to execute your query. It will take care of possible injections.

---

You can find the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

As for an example, after you set up a database connection, use something like this:

```
// add exception handling where necessary
PreparedStatement insertStmt = null;

String query = "INSERT INTO sometable"
            + "(name, value) VALUES"
            + "(?,?)"; //here the question marks stand for parameters 
insertStmt = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
insertStmt.setString(1, "somename"); //set the first param
insertStmt.setInt(2, value); // set the second param

insertStmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will never be certain that you blocked all available SQL statements by using a regular expression. This is a very unstable and error prone approach. I would suggest using either a [prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) or even better an [ORM framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping). You could check [this tutorial regarding hibernate ORM](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/orm_overview.htm) and [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for prepared statements.

These two mechanisms will protect you by definition from SQL injection as they are not based in using user input in their executed SQL, unless you specifically tell them so. Even then, they implement SQL injection protection which are far better than using a regular expression.

Hope I helped!